# How did cells survive before the first appearance of topoisomerases?

Tags: molecular-biology

How did cells operate before the first appearance of topoisomerases to relax DNA supercoils during replication? I read a recent paper on the early phase of topoisomerase evolution, but it doesn’t discuss the actual origin of the topoisomerases, or how cells survived before the first appearance of topoisomerases. Here is the paper:

Villain, P. et al, “Expanded Dataset Reveals the Emergence and Evolution of DNA Gyrase in Archaea.” Mol. Biol. Evol. 39(8), https://doi.org/10.1093/molbev/msac155